# Animating a gif W/O using PIL

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am currently trying to make life easier by having the code pull all the frames into my code and execute the animation. My current code is:

```
import time
from tkinter import *
import os



root = Tk()


imagelist = []
for file in os.listdir("MY-DIRECTORY"):
    if file.endswith(".gif"):
        imagelist.append(PhotoImage(file=str(os.path.join("MY-DIRECTORY", file))))


# extract width and height info
photo = PhotoImage(file=imagelist[0])
width = photo.width()
height = photo.height()
canvas = Canvas(width=width, height=height)
canvas.pack()
# create a list of image objects
giflist = []
for imagefile in imagelist:
    photo = PhotoImage(file=imagefile)
    giflist.append(photo)
# loop through the gif image objects for a while
for k in range(0, 1000):
    for gif in giflist:
        canvas.create_image(width / 2.0, height / 2.0, image=gif)
        canvas.update()
        time.sleep(0.1)
root.mainloop()
```

When I try to execute the file it gives me this error which I cannot make sense of.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Profile/Desktop/folder (2.22.2019)/animation2.py", line 21, in <module>
    photo = PhotoImage(file=imagelist[0])
  File "C:\Users\Profile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3545, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Profile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3501, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "pyimage1": no such file or directory
```

Note: I am adapting this code to fit my needs I did not write it.

I ran some print statements to verify the pyimage was being uploaded to the array but I cannot figure out why its saying there is no such file or directory if its already uploaded to the array. Can you all please shine some light.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I was creating an unnecessary array of objects lower in the code. `giflist[]`. I ultimately resolved the issue by removing it and having the loop use the array that was created earlier in the code `imagelist`. The following code works now.

```
import time
from tkinter import *
import os

root = Tk()  

imagelist = []
for file in os.listdir("My-Directory"):
    if file.endswith(".gif"):
        imagelist.append(PhotoImage(file=str(os.path.join("My-Directory", file))))

# Extract width and height info
photo = PhotoImage(file="My-Directory")
width = photo.width()
height = photo.height()
canvas = Canvas(width=width, height=height)
canvas.pack()

# Loop through the gif image objects for a while
for k in range(0, len(imagelist)):
    for gif in imagelist:
        canvas.create_image(width / 2.0, height / 2.0, image=gif)
        canvas.update()
        time.sleep(0.1)
root.mainloop()
```